# PHP Pear Email Text Encoding not being excepted

Tags: php, email, header, pear, multipart

How do I correctly set the text encoding for a multi-part email using `Pear`?

I've looked at many examples and I believe I am setting  it correctly. However, When sending emails they are arriving with `charset=ISO-8859-1` even though I specify `UTF-8`.

This problem began when I decided to send a multi-part email with both text and HTML parts. I have tried setting a content type but it does not appear to make a difference.

Below is the code I am using. Any suggestions appreciated.

```
function send_html_email($to, $from, $subject, $html, $plainTxt ) {
    require_once "Mail.php";
    require_once "Mail/mime.php";    

    $host = "ssl://secure.xxx.com";
    $port = "xxx";
    $username = "xxx";
    $password = "xxx";

    $headers = array (
    'charset' => 'UTF-8',
    'From' => $from,
            'To' => $to,
            'Subject' => $subject,
        'MIME-Version' => "1.0"
             );  

    $crlf = "\n";
            $mime = new Mail_mime($crlf);

    $mime->setHTMLBody($html); 
    $mime->setTXTBody($plainTxt); 
            $body = $mime->get();
            $headers = $mime->headers($headers);

            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host,
    'port' => $port,
    'auth' => true,
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $password)); 

            $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try headers like such:

```
$headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"";
$headers['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] = "8bit";
```

Reference: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail.factory.php#13207

As a side note, Pear is "a framework and distribution system for reusable PHP components". The Mail component is just one of the many available through Pear.

Comment: Thx, Actually I found the fix, but not the answer other than that it must be specified in another way. Its in the comments section of this pagehttp://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php

Comment: I found the fix, I guess it needs to be specified differently! 

You Pass a set of params to the the mime get function, like this. 

`$mimeparams['text_encoding']="8bit";
$mimeparams['text_charset']="UTF-8";
$mimeparams['html_charset']="UTF-8";
$mimeparams['head_charset']="UTF-8";

$body = $mime->get($mimeparams);`

Does not appear to be documented all that well. Found it here in the user notes area.
[http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.mail.mail-mime.example.php]